# Why do some programs have higher TCP latency periods than other programs?

Tags: networking

Why do some programs have higher TCP latency periods than other programs?

[image]

([View larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsHvO.jpg))

See the latency column under TCP connections.

In addition, why does process ID 2272 have more activity (in terms of B/sec sent) under "Processes with Network Activity" than under "Network Activity"?

Answer (score 2):

Latency means delay.  All connections to different hosts are going to have different latencies; that's pretty normal.  Also, measured latency typically varies even to a given host as network paths and traffic affect delivery time.  It is possible that TCP latency means something special in this case, but I don't know what that would be.

If you look further down under "Network Activity", you'll see process ID 2272 listed again, with a connection to a second host.  If you sum all of the connections for process 2272, I suspect you will get the total under "Processes with Network activity".